# Internet Explorer is not showing an image in the homepage

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

I developed a website with WordPress and it is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but there is an issue with Internet Explorer. On the home page, the first image that should be centered right at the bottom of the nav bar is not showing up. Instead, there is an X and a lot of blank space.

Here is a piece of the HTML example of the homepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    #logo {
      display: none;
    }

    div img {
      display: inline;
    }

    div footer-area {
      display: none;
    }

</style>
<head>
<img style="margin: -76px auto -55px auto; width: 100%; max-width: 450px;" src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo.png" alt="" width="1800" height="903" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-461" />
</head>
<body>
<div>[smartslider3 slider=4]</div>
```

Here is the link at the website: http://www.albertonesso.it

What shall I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The src of the image is pointing to your localhost and not your website address.  Change it to albertonesso.it

```
http://localhost/wp/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo.png
```

to

```
http://www.albertonesso.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logo.png
```